# Why does this saved xml file can't be displayed locally?

Tags: xml, lxml

I am trying to parse an xml file from SEC's website. The link is [here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1065899/000114554916016542/xslN-MFP1_X01/primary_doc.xml). It shows well on the website. However, when I saved the xml file and related images and css file and tried to open it locally. I see the error message: *error on line 6 at column 20: Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 0 and head*. The file also can not be parsed by lxml python package due to mismatched tag.

Why is that?

Comment: The document is not well-formed and therefore it is not an XML document. It might be possible to parse it using lxml.html (https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html).

Comment: I agree. But why it is renderable on the web?

Comment: Most web browsers are forgiving. They fix or accept many kinds of errors that a strict XML parser rejects.